# DataContract for different data structure

Tags: c#, datamapper, datacontractserializer

I have two data provider , they have different data structures. I must to map its structure to myself. 
I use following code for the aim :

```
[DataContract]
class Mapper1
{
    [DataMember(Name="DataID")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Time")]
    public DateTime d_time { get; set; }
}
class Mapper2
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ID")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "DATE")]
    public DateTime d_time { get; set; }
}
```

I think there's better way to do it. Does anybody know ?

Comment: I assume your internal data has some common data class that you are copying into each of these structures?

Comment: Yes, I do as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with different data sources it is often a good idea to have a separation in structure.  This will help isolate issues with the different areas of the software when coding.  In short, you may want to have better naming conventions for your mappers, and perhaps separate them by namespaces to help distinguish them in the code.

The use of [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) will also help with creating mapping code between the data providers.  This way you can focus on the domain language that is appropriate for each provider.

Below is an example that demonstrates using automapper.  It uses a bit of code, but in the long run with a large project having the declarative mappings between data types is much cleaner and easier to debug.

```
namespace Provider1
{
   [DataContract]
   public class Data
   {
      [DataMember]
      public int DataID { get; set; }
      [DataMember]
      public DateTime Time { get; set; }
   }
}

namespace Provider2
{
   [DataContract]
   public class Data
   {
      [DataMember]
      public int ID { get; set; }
      [DataMember]
      public DateTime DATE { get; set; }
   }
}

namespace Internal
{
   public class Data
   {
      public int id { get; set; }
      public DateTime d_time { get; set; }
   }
} 

public static class Configuration
{
   public static void InitMappers()
   {
      AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Internal.Data, Provider1.Data>()
         .ForMember(x=> x.DataID, opt=> opt.MapFrom(src=> src.id))
         .ForMember(x=> x.Time, opt=> opt.MapFrom(src => src.d_time)); 

     AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Internal.Data, Provider2.Data> ()
        .ForMember (x => x.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom (src => src.id))
        .ForMember (x => x.DATE, opt => opt.MapFrom (src => src.d_time));
   }
}

public class TestExample
{
   public void Test()
   {
      var src = new Internal.Data ();
      var dest = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Provider1.Data> (src);
      var dest2 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Provider2.Data> (dest);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. Your answer is realy good. But I will use Interface design.

Comment: No worries, not every problem calls for the same answer and this solution really depends on how complex the data classes you are dealing with become.  Keep in mind as your application grows that you can always refactor the code to a more structured style if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should actually have the same contract work for two different data sources. But if you needed to use them interchangeably, you have some options like making them both inherit from a common interface

```
interface
{
    int Id {get; set;}
    DateTime Updated {get; set;}
}
```

dynamics

```
dynamic myMapper = new Mapper1();

Console.WriteLine(myMapper.Id);
```

or the best option in my opinion is to map them both to a common model using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or a similar tool

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best design for the present:

```
public interface MyDataStructure
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime d_time { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
class Mapper1:MyDataStructure
{
    [DataMember(Name="DataID")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Time")]
    public DateTime d_time { get; set; }
}
class Mapper2:MyDataStructure
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ID")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "DATE")]
    public DateTime d_time { get; set; }
}
```